# Hidden Friend Concept in C++

Tags: c++, friend, idioms

I'm still a beginner in C++ trying to learn more about the language. I recently read about the concept of ADL (Argument-Dependent Lookup) and Hidden Friends idiom (https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/argument-dependent-lookup-and-hidden-friends). My understanding of ADL is that in the case of an unqualified function call, C++ looks for the function in not only the current namespace, but also the namespace of the argument type.

I'm confused at what the point of the hidden friend idiom is, and what hidden friend means exactly (i.e. what is hidden about it). I get that friend functions of a class are non-member functions but can access private members of the class. However, I don't see why they are necessary. In the code example given in the reading, it points out the necessity of friends in the given functions specifically for general overloads with two parameters of a custom class. That is, in

```
class MyDistance{
  public:
    explicit MyDistance(double i):m(i){}

    MyDistance operator +(const MyDistance& a, const MyDistance& b){
        return MyDistance(a.m + b.m);
    }
    
    friend MyDistance operator -(const MyDistance& a, const MyDistance& b){
        return MyDistance(a.m - b.m);
    }
    
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, const MyDistance& myDist){
        out << myDist.m << " m";
        return out;
    }

  private:
    double m;

};
```

The + operator overload for the class is not a friend, is a member function, and technically takes in 3 parameters of `MyDistance` here I believe since it is a member function (this) and takes 2 additional parameters, making it invalid.

However, instead of having a hidden friend, couldn't we just write the code as

```
class MyDistance{
  public:
    ...
    
    MyDistance operator +(const MyDistance& other){
        return MyDistance(m + other.m);
    }
    ...
};
```

Is there any downside to writing the code like this? Is it slower (at compile time) in some way due to the order in which C++ does the lookup (perhaps looking at non-member functions before looking at member functions)? Also, what exactly is the "hidden friend idiom" supposed to "hide"? Is it that the function itself is defined in the class instead of outside?

Comment: There are no real downsides for member operators. It's just syntax. In some situation it can be better to write a free function but it is irrelevant in this case. The `friend` is required for operator whose first parameter is not an instance of this class. Like the operator `<<` you have here.

Comment: It a new concept to me but [this](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/cplusplus/hidden-friends.html) seems like a better article on hidden friends though even here I think some of the code is a little wonky.

Comment: The "hidden" part of a hidden friend is that it is *only* found by ADL. This restricts its use to cases where you actually have an object of the class type, but excludes uses of types only *convertible* to the type. Sometimes that is what you want. (This was discovered for [path operator<<](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2989) where a wide string could be converted to a narrow string via a temporary `path` object. Oops!).

Comment: @BoP Why can the hidden friend only be found by ADL, err what does that mean exactly? I do see how ADL is able to find it since it looks at the namespace of the argument type, which includes the friend function. However, isn't this the case when we make the + operator overload a member function as well? Is there another way of calling the + function if it isn't a hidden friend?

Comment: "Only found by ADL" means that the "hidden friend" is only visible when we  already have an object of the class type. and therefore look inside the class. Otherwise the compiler can find a free function/operator first, and only then consider conversions to the class type to match the parameters. The hidden friend is not visible outside of the class, so will never be considered in the first phase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Is there any downside?* Yes, in your example above C++ applies different rules to the two arguments of operator+. Specifically the left hand argument must be an object of type `MyDistance` but the right hand argument can be any type convertible to `MyDistance`.

Extending your example a little

```
class MyDistance{
  public:
    ...
    MyDistance(int dist) { ... }

    MyDistance operator+(const MyDistance& other) const {
        return MyDistance(m + other.m);
    }
    ...
};
```

With this code

```
MyDistance x(1);
MyDistance y = x + 2;
```

is legal because there is a conversion from `int` to `MyDistance` but this is illegal

```
MyDistance x(1);
MyDistance y = 2 + x;
```

because given the declaration above the left hand side of `+` must be a `MyDistance` object.

There is no such problem when `operator+` is a friend, in that case either argument can be convertible to `MyDistance` and both versions of the code above are legal.

Our expectation of `operator+` is that it is symmetric, so the friend version is better because it applies the same rules to both arguments.

Comment: If anything to me it looks more of a con rather than pro. Having such implicit conversions is not a good idea and that the operator adding extra dimension of freedom can lead to problematic and unexpected resolutions.

Comment: @ALX23z That depends, but if you don't want implicit conversions then don't code them in your class in the first place. You may get implicit conversions with either method of writing a binary operator, the only difference is whether they are applied symmetrically or not.

Comment: if I wanted the operator to accept a collection of classes I'd write a template that properly declares what it accepts rather than rely on something as fickle and unreliable as implicit conversion.

Comment: so yeah. No implicit conversion. Does making the operator into friend add anything of value?

Comment: I see what you mean. Do you happen to also know how C++ compiler goes from a+b to a.operator+(b) to operator+(a, b)? Are there other possible functions that C++ calls to resolve a+b, and what's the order in which C++ tries these functions? I defined both the member operator + overload and the hidden friend one and it looks like C++ (at least in gcc) prioritizes the member operator. Does this lead to any compile-time speed ups?

Comment: @JohnJames You are going to have to ask someone more expert than me. However I can't imagine that this issue would make any difference to how fast your code is compiled.

Answer (score 3):

##### Hidden Friends Are Your Friend

**Dan Saks** gave a great talk explaining hidden friends at CppCon2018. It is entitled [Making New Friends](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=POa_V15je8Y).

In addition to the issues explained by @john, templates are another big reason for mastering the "hidden friends" idiom.

The stream insertion and extraction operators, `operator<<` and `operator>>` are best written in terms of `std::basic_ostream` and `std::basic_istream`, the templates on which `std::ostream` and `std::istream`are based. Written that way, the operators will work with any character type.

When the objects you are reading and writing are themselves templates, things can get complicated fast. If the stream insertion and extraction operator functions are not hidden inside the object class, and are instead written outside of it, you have to use template paramaters both for the object and the stream. When the operator functions are written as hidden friends, inside of the object class, you still need to supply template parameters, but only for the stream (and not for the object).

Suppose, for instance, you decide to add a template parameter to class `MyDistance`. If `operator<<` is not a hidden friend, the code might look like the following. This `operator<<` resides in the scope outside of class MyDistance, and can be found without ADL.

This is a complete program (it runs):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template< typename NumType >
class MyDistance {
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic_v<NumType>, "");
public:
    explicit MyDistance(NumType i) :m(i) {}

    // ...

    // This is a declaration that says, in essence, "In the 
    // scope outside this class, there is visible a definition 
    // for the templated operator<< declared here, and that 
    // operator function template is my friend." 
    // 
    // Although it is a friend, it is not hidden.
    //
    // operator<< requires three template parameters.
    // Parameter NumType2 is distinct from NumType.
    template< typename charT, typename traits, typename NumType2 >
    friend auto operator<< (
        std::basic_ostream<charT, traits>& out,
        const MyDistance<NumType2>& myDist
        )
        -> std::basic_ostream<charT, traits>&;

private:
    NumType m;
};

// operator<< is not hidden, because it is defined outside
// of class MyDistance, and it is therefore visible in the 
// scope outside class MyDistance. It can be found without ADL.
//
// Here we can use NumType, NumType2, T, or anything else 
// as the third template parameter. It's just a name.
template< typename charT, typename traits, typename NumType >
auto operator<< (
    std::basic_ostream<charT, traits>& out,
    const MyDistance<NumType>& myDist
    )
    -> std::basic_ostream<charT, traits>&
{
    out << myDist.m << " m";
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    MyDistance<int> md_int{ 42 };
    MyDistance<double> md_double{ 3.14 };
    std::cout 
        << "MyDistance<int>    : " << md_int << '\n' 
        << "MyDistance<double> : " << md_double << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

When written as a hidden friend, the code is both cleaner and more consise. This `operator<<` is not visible in the scope outside class MyDistance, and can only be found with ADL.

This is also a complete program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template< typename NumType >
class MyDistance {
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic_v<NumType>, "");
public:
    explicit MyDistance(NumType i) :m(i) {}

    // ...

    // operator<< has only the two template parameters 
    // required by std::basic_ostream. It is only visible 
    // within class MyDistance, so it is "hidden." 
    //
    // You cannot scope to it either, using the scope resolution 
    // operator(::), because it is not a member of the class!
    // 
    // It is truly hidden, and can only be found with ADL.
    template< typename charT, typename traits>
    friend auto operator<< (
        std::basic_ostream<charT, traits>& out,
        const MyDistance& myDist
        )
        -> std::basic_ostream<charT, traits>&
    {
        out << myDist.m << " m";
        return out;
    }

private:
    NumType m;
};

int main()
{
    MyDistance<int> md_int{ 42 };
    MyDistance<double> md_double{ 3.14 };
    std::cout
        << "MyDistance<int>    : " << md_int << '\n'
        << "MyDistance<double> : " << md_double << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Now, imagine that MyDistance is a more complicated object, with many template parameters, some of which themselves might be templated.

A few years ago I constructed class `RomanNumeral<IntType>` to do arithmetic with Roman numerals. I also wrote class `Rational<IntType>` to do arithmetic with rational numbers, where numerator and denominator were stored separately. Then I got the bright idea of allowing rational numbers to be constructed with Roman numerals! But I also wanted class Rational to continue working with integers. What a mess! It took real care to get the stream operators working so they would output things like: xiii/c.

It's a great exercise. One of the things you will learn if you try it, is that hidden friends are your friend!