# Difficulty separating header/source of a class within a namespace while using operator overload

Tags: c++, class, scope, header, namespaces

My separation of a class between a header/source seems to work until I try to work with the declaration of the class within a namespace. I believe it has to do with the scope of the operator within the specified namespace, but I don't know the syntax to correctly overload the operator in this way.

`NameTest.h`

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

namespace testspace
{
    class Test
    {
    private:
        int number{};
    
    public:
        friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Test& test);
    };
}
```

`NameTest.cpp`

```
#include "NameTest.h"

using namespace testspace;

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Test& test)
{
    out << test.number;
    return out;
}
```

I know it is resolving like this in the header...

`(std::ostream &testspace::operator<< (std::ostream &out, const testspace::Test& test);`

...and I think it has something to do with scope resolution, but I don't know if it is a problem with the way I am implementing the namespace, the operator, or the class itself. I do know, at least, that when I remove the class declaration from the namespace it works fine. Does it have to do with scope resolution within the .cpp? And how would I implement that?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: test.number is inaccessible within the definition of the operator overload as it stands...

Comment: `using namespace X;` just adds a namespace for lookup purposes. To define something in a namespace you need `namespace X { ... }`

Comment: `namespace testspace {

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Test& test)
{ ... }
}` in the source file - just like in the header file.

Comment: @heap underrun - so will I run into any trouble having 'namespace testspace {' in both the header and the source? Or does it simply append what exists within the namespace?

Comment: You can open a namespace with `namespace foo {` to add things to it, as many times as you need in different files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say `using namespace testspace;` in the source file, that just imports names from the namespace for name lookup. If you want to add things to the namespace, like your `operator<<`, then you need to open up the namespace with

```
namespace testspace {
```

and then add the implementation of the operator and then close the namespace again

```
}
```

You can open up a namespace for additions as many times as you need/want, across multiple files or inside the same file. It's all additive.

Answer (score 1):

##### The special status of operator functions

There is a subtle reason that the definition of `operator<<` must be made inside namespace `testspace`. It has to do with the special status given to `operator` functions that are declared in a class. Usually, the members of a class must be referenced using the `dot operator`. We don't, however, generally do that with operators. Instead, *we just use them*.

This works because the operators declared inside a class are automatically made visible *in the scope where the class is declared*. That is the place where the linker looks when it needs to find a definition for your friend operator.

You have told the linker that your operator is defined in namespace `testspace`, but the operator you define in file `NameTest.cpp` resides at "file level".

The fix is the one given by @Jesper Juhl. Move the definition into namespace `testspace`.

```cpp
// NameTest.cpp
#include "NameTest.h"
using namespace testspace;
namespace testspace
{
    std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Test& test)
    {
        out << test.number;
        return out;
    }
}
```

##### Overkill proves the point

Here is a little overkill that proves the point. This is what you would do if you were determined to keep the definition of `operator<<` at the "file level."

```cpp
// NameTest.h
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

namespace testspace
{
    // Forward declaration tells everyone that class Test 
    // resides in namespace testspace.
    class Test;
}
// The operator declared here is declared at the "file-level".
// Its right operand, however, will be found in namespace testspace.
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const testspace::Test& test);

namespace testspace
{
    class Test
    {
    private:
        int number{};

    public:
        // The friend declared here uses namespace scoping to indicate 
        // that operator<< is defined at "file-level". Note the :: right 
        // before the keyword operator.
        friend std::ostream& ::operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Test& test);
    };
}
```

```cpp
// NameTest.cpp
#include "NameTest.h"
using namespace testspace;

// This operator is defined at the "file level."
// The right operand must be scoped to namespace testspace.
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const testspace::Test& test)
{
    out << test.number;
    return out;
}
```

This program runs, as do the others given in this answer. I tested them with the following driver that outputs `t : 0`.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "NameTest.h"
int main()
{
    testspace::Test t;
    std::cout << "t : " << t << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

##### A hidden friends alternative

In general, however, I do not like either of the answers given above. Instead, I would use the "hidden friends" idiom. That method simply moves the definition of `operator<<` into the class itself.

You can learn more about hidden friends in my answer to this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76746760/hidden-friend-concept-in-c/76749466#76749466).

I frequently `inline` the operator, but that is not strictly necessary.

```cpp
// NameTest.h
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

namespace testspace
{
    class Test
    {
    private:
        int number{};

    private:
        inline friend auto operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Test& test)
            -> std::ostream&
        {
            out << test.number;
            return out;
        }
    };
}
```

In order to avoid confusion, I normally declare my hidden friends as `public`. In this example, however, I made it `private`. In fact, the `access specifier` can be `public`, `private` or `protected`. It does not matter which. Friendship has nothing to do with access specifiers.

The hidden friend that is being defined *is not a member of the class.* It is an operator that is visible in the scope outside the class, and which, in effect, resides there. For a function that is not a member of a class, and which resides outside the class, it makes no sense to talk about `public`, `private`, and `protected`.

BTW, if you use the hidden-friend idiom, don't forget to remove the definition of `operator<<` from file `NameTest.cpp`.

*Side notes:*

1. When you need to have a namespace with a long name, consider using a "namespace alias." Here, for example, I would probably create the alias `ts` for `testspace`.

```cpp
namespace ts = testspace;
```

2. Most of the time, you do not want to use "using directives" such as `using namespace testspace` and `using namespace std`. Just write out the fully scoped names you need. Given the namespace alias `ts`, for instance, it is easy to write `ts::Test`, and so on.

Comment: In NameTest.h did you mean the `friend ::operator<<` as **namespace** scoped instead of file-level as you mentioned?

Comment: @Iron Fist: Yes. In `NameTest.cpp`, `operator<<` is _defined_ at "file-level." In the `friend` declaration from `NameTest.h`, I use namespace scoping to indicate the namespace where that definition can be found. Names defined at "file-level" are sometimes said to be in the "global" namespace.

Comment: then please update your comment in the `NameTest.h` file, at `friend ::operator<<`, that was my remark here

Comment: @Iron Fist: Done.